# A guess that the Swift type alias mechanism is the automatic initializer Inheritance

Tags: swift, initialization, type-alias

The question popped in my head, what is happening when I define a Swift type alias? What is the mechanism behind it? Until I learned the Automatic Initializer Inheritance chapter from the Swift official document:

> If your subclass doesn't define any designated initializer, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers

And here is my practice code for learning

```
class Vehicle{
    var numberOfWheels = 0
    var description: String {
        return "\(numberOfWheels) wheel(s)"
    }
}

class Auto: Vehicle{}

let VM = Auto()
VM.numberOfWheels
```

Wow! this works,at least performs, exactly as the Swift type alias. **Auto** is the alias of the type **Vehicle**

Question: Am I understand it right? This is the mechanism behind type alias.

Comment: `Auto` is not a type alias, it's a subclass of  `Vehicle`

Comment: @vadian So the type alias actually in the same level of the original class it defined from. But subclass is in the Sub level, it inherited from the super class

Comment: A type alias is a synonym which can be used instead of the original term, for example `NSTimeInterval` is a type alias of `Double` and can be used wherever a `Double` is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but if you've never seen object oriented programming they could look somewhat similar, i agree.

`Auto` is a subclass that *extends* the original vehicle and could add additional properties and method to the `Vehicle` even if in that example it doesn't do it.

`Auto` and `Vehicle` are not the same thing, a `Vehicle` is a basic type and and `Auto` is one of its subtypes, what you can do with a `Vehicle` you can do with an `Auto` but not vice-versa.

A typealias is just an *alias*, a way to give and additional "name" to a pre-existing type, just that. A type and his alias are the same thing.

Comment: "what you can do with a Vehicle you can do with an Auto but not vice-versa." What a good explanation! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

*Question: Am I understand it right? This is the mechanism behind type alias.*

NO, typealises and subclassing (with inheriting all methods and initializers) are different things and based on different semantics and mechanisms.

```
let v1 = Vehicle()
v1 is Auto //->false

typealias Norimono = Vehicle
v1 is Norimono //->true (with warning "'is' test is always true)
```

The last result (including the warning you may find) is exactly the same as `v1 is Vehicle`.

Typealias is literally an alias, it's giving another name for the same type.

---

One more, you can define typealias of structs or enums, which you cannot define inherited classes (types).

Comment: Very nice example and the extra information, Thanks a lot :)